# Describing failing assert statements in imported functions with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest nicely prints the values of variables in failing assert statement (e.g. example [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#asserting-with-the-assert-statement)).

However, this does not work for assert failures in imported functions,

**example.py**

```
def func():
    b = 1
    assert b == 0
```

**test_func.py**

```
from example import func

def test_func():
    func()
```

running `pytest test_example.py` will yield,

```
    def test_func():
>       func()

test_example.py:4: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def func():
        b = 1
>       assert b == 0
E       AssertionError

example.py:4: AssertionError
```

in other words it will not print debug information about why that assertion failed (namely that the value of b is 1).

Is there a way around this? Should I open a Github issue in the Pytest repo?

**Note:** if I put the function definition in the same `test_example.py` I do get the expected result,

```
    def func():
        b = 1
>       assert b == 0
E       assert 1 == 0

test_example.py:3: AssertionError
```

but in many use cases one can't do that (e.g. assert fails in some package), hence my question...

Comment: It should working, just tested it locally and report the why it's failing and displaying `b` value. If also you check docs should be working: [assert](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html) & [failure demo](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.9.1/example/reportingdemo.html)

Comment: Thanks for checking. You will notice that in both of those examples, the functions are defined in the same test file and are not imported from elsewhere. That works fine. I updated my question above. But in many use cases you can't do that (e.g. assert fails in some package), hence my question...

Comment: Aha I got it, you are right.

Comment: Is example.py in the PTYHONPATH directory? What it you add assert b==0, "b wasn't equal 0" etc.

Comment: It's in the current folder, so yes it is. Yes that would work, but the whole point of pytest here is that is should do the work of generating the exception message for you...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [pytest.register_assert_rewrite](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-register-assert-rewrite) function, to enable this functionality for your modules.

You must call register_assert_rewrite before you import your function from the module, so you can place it conftest.py for example.

**conftest.py**

```py
import pytest
pytest.register_assert_rewrite("example")
```

Link to original solution: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4671

Answer (score 0):

In basic way you need to ask for verbose output:

`py.test -vvvv`

Additionally you can specify the level of verbosity:

```
logging.WARN,    # -v
logging.INFO,    # -vv
logging.DEBUG,   # -vvv
logging.TRACE,   # -vvvv
logging.GARBAGE  # -vvvvv
```

For even more custom logging you can check [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Just tried that (with Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.2, Linux), it doesn't not change the fact that I only get an `AssertionError` with no additional details..